# a4j:mediaOutput with large mp3 files

Tags: java, ajax, richfaces, seam

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I added:

```
<h:form id="media">
<a4j:mediaOutput id="aud"  element="object" cacheable="false" session="true"
    title="canYouSeeMe"
    width="300"
        createContent="#{mediaPlay.play}"
        value="#{sdh:storeDataAndGetKey(mediaPlay.selectedFileData)}"
        mimeType="audio/x-mpeg" />
</h:form>
```

When I first opened the page in Firefox I got a message that I needed to install the QuickTime plugin.  But nothing else.  I see no link or way to play the audio in FF or IE.  The recursive storeDataAndGetKey method I got from a tutorial here:
https://community.jboss.org/wiki/A4jmediaOutputAndLargeObjectsAsValue
for large objects.

```
private static DataHolder getGraphDataHolder() {
        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        ExternalContext externalContext = fc.getExternalContext();
        Map<String, Object> sessionMap = externalContext.getSessionMap();
        Object session = externalContext.getSession(true);
        DataHolder holder;
        synchronized (session) {
            holder = (DataHolder) sessionMap.get(DATA_HOLDER_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
            if(holder == null){
                holder = new DataHolder();
                sessionMap.put(DATA_HOLDER_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, holder);
            }
        }
        return holder;
    }

    public static Object getDataByKey(Object key) {
        DataHolder holder = getGraphDataHolder();

        return holder.getDataByKey(key);
    }
```

mediaPlay.play:

```
public synchronized void play (OutputStream stream, Object object) throws IOException {
     Object restoredData = SessionDataHelper.getDataByKey(object);
     byte[] soundData = ((Data) restoredData).getFileData();
     stream.write(soundData);
}
```

I can see the component in the page source, but not in the rendered page.  I'm not even sure what I'm supposed to see.

**EDIT TO ADD RAW HTML**
after the page loads

```
<form id="j_id18:media" name="j_id18:media" method="post" action="/home.seam" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="j_id18:media" value="j_id18:media" />
<object id="j_id18:media:aud" data="/a4j/s/3_3_1.GAorg.ajax4jsf.resource.UserResource/n/s/-1007594989/DATA/eAFlUs9rE0EUfl0stv4Aa6ziQai1KIiZmGS3UWpBUFEhsWJsQT297L4ks8zurDOz6WrRmxcFL169edWL!gVeC176NwgiIoggXp2dFKV1DgNv-N73fe978!Y7TGoFZ6UaMIyx8GPdZ4q0zFVIbFWTurNdLKwqfhUNQnkqwTcP9rThYKgIDV2RqaHUGDjcjnGENYHpoLbSiyk0S23YS0XGLedDeAoTbZhKZMT7nKLtenKEIidXFJn1crqkKFgfQ9IslEkmU8vNusYK3ZAiItXFEal7mx-WX73-1PHAa8N0KFDrW5jQTg9do3g6sB72adsTOQ4DR8cuuax1SXEU!DH2BC0VWSl!xkoynafOgCCjGQl2FwcdMkMZXSsyO4nmMnU5AEwcACgUHB-bttDduPe1zReff!svPYer!MX9Y3rz7Hn35!2tSyWidHCyXEbck9pJ7-a7mWSi9-PYr!0fZzqldhnc1PoszJzaSCjieFvgI5bZ6wlArqDywA3LypXYDF0c77bWvnw9sXHdCdo5PANHSl-MS7aSmyw3FkiYGDjknl3veJ1ZVqwvgl8byoRYMTSJmLvcWDzXDOZ2!ITl-f!czNt4DSy0ggZSE!1qENYvVP3zF6mKjSCq9lutRp2CZt0Pmn8A3l!elQ__" title="canYouSeeMe" width="300"></object><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="j_id2" />

</form>
```

This is Seam 2.2, RichFaces 3.3.3.  Running on JBoss 5.1

Comment: Can you post a link to the generated HTML page?

Comment: I can't link to the page, I added the pertinent page source, the page itself doesn't display any way to play the audio.

Comment: What does Firebug's Network tab report regarding the request for the audio stream?

Comment: Have you ever found a solution for this? I am having the same exact issue and have not been able to find anything.

Comment: no, sorry, never did.